# Correct usage of 'you'?

Tags: grammar

I need a little help with the phrase 'You are...'
For simplicity, I'm going to you the example: 'You are helpful.' It's an awkward example, yes, but it's the best I could find. :P

Are these correct?

Patronizing someone, being sarcastic: Anata wa yūyō desu.

Complimenting a friend (named Joe): Joe-kun wa(?) yūyō desu!

Complimenting a teacher: Sensei yūyō wa(?) desu!

However, I struggle with addressing someone whose name you don't know politely. You can't just say 'Yūyō desu' if they don't know you're addressing them, and 'anata wa' can sound rude!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you are trying to say. what is  yūyō ?

Comment: @probablyme, fill me in as to what the word being used is?

Comment: I know what 有用 is, I just don't see why it is used here.

Comment: Although (as others have mentioned) you can often omit personal pronouns in Japanese, I can also understand why, as a language learner, you might wish to explicitly use them as a "safety net".  For this purpose you can often use the person's social status/role relative to yourself as a pronoun.  For example 先輩 (senpai) for a senior coworker, 部長 (buchou) for a department head, 先生 (sensei) for a teacher, etc.  For this reason alone, it is very useful to learn the formal titles of relevant work positions if you work, etc.

Comment: If you're referring to something that someone did that was helpful, I'd use 役に立つ

Comment: "You are helpful" (with no sarcasm) >> 「助かります。」「助かりました。」とか・・・

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, sarcasm does not work well with the Japanese language.

If you are trying to be Patronizing , I suggest taking the direct approach.

Patronizing someone

> おまえは使{つか}い物{もの}にならん

If you really want to use 「有用{ようよう}」
Complimenting a friend (named Joe)

> ジョー君{くん}は有用{ゆうよう}な人材{じんざい}だ

You could also use this,which has a slightly different meaning.

> ジョー君{くん}は優秀{ゆうしゅう}な人材{じんざい}だ

Complimenting a teacher,

> ありがとうございました。

I can't see a student ever saying that a teacher is needed in this way in Japanese, so if you ever want to thank a teacher for being using just say "Thank you"

Comment: Thank you, but that was just the example, heh! My question was mostly just 'how do you say 'you' without knowing the person's name in a polite way'?

Answer (score 1):

Patronizing saying of "you" is お前.

If you know their name, it is ～君、～ちゃん and only name for friends. ～さん, ～様 for higher ranking persons.

If you don't know their name, we usually omit the subject "you" and ask their names but if you know their positions like 部長, you say their position.

In addition 貴殿 and 貴台 are polite sayings of you but they are very literary and we hardly say them now.